# Mocking a service call from a controller, Jasmine using the actual service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've trying to test that a service is called from the controller using a Spy and a mock. Jasmine's error appear that it's trying to call the actual service? What am I doing wrong?

**Controller**

```
angular.module('vsApp').controller('kitsCtrl', function ($scope, productsDataService) {

    productsDataService.getProducts("kit").success(function (data) {

        $scope.products = data;

    });

});
```

**Spec**

```
describe("Kits controller", function () {

    var productsDataServiceMock, $controllerConstructor, scope;

    beforeEach(module('vsApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {

        $controllerConstructor = $controller;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        productsDataServiceMock = {

            getProducts: function(type) {return {};}
        };

    }));

    it('should call the products data service', inject(function () {

        var ctrl = $controllerConstructor('kitsCtrl', {$scope: scope, productsDataService: productsDataServiceMock});

        spyOn(productsDataServiceMock, 'getProducts').andCallThrough();

        expect(productsDataServiceMock.getProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();

    }));

});
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'productsDataService.getProducts("kit").success(function (data) {

            $scope.products = data;

        })')
        at /**removed**/public/app/controllers/kitsCtrl.js:9
```

Comment: Is this your real spec or is it cleaned up? `$controllerConstructor` seems to be undefined within test function.

Comment: @BroiSatse My mistake, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the test:

1. You spy on the mock after having constructed the controller, and thus after the controller has called the mock.
2. The controller expects the service to return an object having a `success()` method, but your mock returns an empty object. So, when calling `success()`, since that method doesn't exist, an exception is thrown.

My advice: don't create a mock. Spy on the real service, and use the real promise API rather than the soon-to-be-deprecated success/error callbacks:

```
angular.module('vsApp').controller('kitsCtrl', function ($scope, productsDataService) {

    productsDataService.getProducts("kit").then(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data;
    });
});
```

and

```
var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, $rootScope) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));

it('should call the products data service', inject(function(productsDataService, $q) {
    spyOn(productsDataService, 'getProducts').andReturn($q.when('someData'));
    $controller('kitsCtrl', {$scope: scope});

    expect(productsDataServiceMock.getProducts).toHaveBeenCalledWith('kit');
    expect($scope.products).toBe('someData');
}));
```